# merging two tables in hive

Tags: sql, hive

i have two tables having same columns and want to create a 3rd table containing all the records of table 1 and table2. i am doing like this. but it is not working. please help

```
select * into R5 from 
(select 
r.account_id as account_id,
r.dim_account_key as dim_account_key,
r.activation_date as activation_date,
r.serial_number as serial_number
from R5_1 r
union all
select 
s.account_id as account_id,
s.dim_account_key as dim_account_key,
s.activation_date as activation_date,
s.serial_number as serial_number
from R5_2 s) R
```

Comment: What is the issue you have with your query?

Answer (score 0):

Hive does not have any "SELECT INTO" statement. I believe you mean "INSERT INTO TABLE". So your query would be like:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE R5
SELECT * FROM 
(select 
r.account_id as account_id,
r.dim_account_key as dim_account_key,
r.activation_date as activation_date,
r.serial_number as serial_number
from R5_1 r
union all
select 
s.account_id as account_id,
s.dim_account_key as dim_account_key,
s.activation_date as activation_date,
s.serial_number as serial_number
from R5_2 s) R
```

Remember that *INSERT INTO TABLE* will append data to the table, if you want to overwrite, replace it to *INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE*